# How to focus visibilty to specific time set in lightweight charts?

Tags: lightweight-charts

As the subject goes:

How to focus visibilty to specific time set in lightweight charts?

Im running this script to do backtesting and its a true pain to find certain markers (im on the 1 minute so i have 1000+ rows of price rows)

I know the time of the candle i want to see how do I focus on it?

Answer (score 1):

To read/write data to lightweight-charts time scale, use the **ITimeScaleApi**. You're likely looking for the [setVisibleLogicalRange](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/ITimeScaleApi#setvisiblelogicalrange) or [scrollToPosition](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/ITimeScaleApi#scrolltoposition) methods.